# What is the difference between enterAnim & popEnterAnim & exitAnim & popExitAnim?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-architecture-navigation

What is the difference between animation tags in latest Navigation Architecture Component? I got confused with `enterAnim` & `popEnterAnim`. Similarly, `exitAnim` & `popExitAnim`.

Any visual expansions is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The [Animate transitions between destinations documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions) details the four types of animations:

> - Entering a destination
> - Exiting a destination
> - Entering a destination via a [pop action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#pop)
> - Exiting a destination via a pop action

"Entering" refers to the destination that is coming onto the screen, while "exiting" refers to the destination leaving the screen.

Therefore when you navigate from destination `A` to destination `B`, the entering destination `B` will have the `enterAnim` applied to it and the exiting destination `A` will have the `exitAnim` applied to it.

When the user hits the system Back button, going from `B` **back** to `A`, the reverse happens: the entering destination `A` will have the `popEnterAnim` applied to it and the exiting destination `B` will have the `popExitAnim` applied to it.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake Would be awesome to see this in the documentation!

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár - I linked to the documentation where this is covered. What exactly were you missing?

Comment: It could be just me, but reading through the documentation wasn't clear which animation will affect which fragment, it just mentions the types I could use. Your explanation on the other hand clearly explains which fragment will be animated using which animation type. So I missed the example part from the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: @ianhanniballake The documentation wording is kinda left to interpretation without your example. "Entering a destination" for me means A is entering B because if B is the destination then B can't be the reference because it would mean B is entering itself because it itself is the destination... If this sounds confusing, this is how precisely the documentation explains it.

Comment: This should be in the official documentation about animation and navigation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Comment: +1 to adding this to documentation. Having it here would be great https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Answer (score 12):

**Pop is related to the back stack**, I use back stack for helping understanding

e.g.

`A` is showing on screen now, we are going to put `B` on screen, then `A` will **Exit**(Anim/transaction) from screen, `B` will **Enter** to screen.

Now what’s going to happen if you tap back key/up button? Yes, the reverse happens. Which means `B` is going to be replaced by `A`.

- `B` is **popped off the back stack** and Exit from screen (**Pop
  Exit**)
- `A` is entered to the view from the **back stack** (**Pop    Enter**)

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that I'm answering a three-year-old question, but I have a slightly different understanding of the `enterAnim`, `exitAnim`, `popEnterAnim` and `popExitAnim` than what is presented in the accepted answer by @ianhanniballake.

In my interpretation, all four attributes are targeting the same destination in the graph: the one defined by the `app:destination` attribute of the given `<action>`. The `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` is applied when navigating to or from the destination the "regular way", while `popEnterAnim` is applied to the destination when it is shown as a result of the destination "above" it being popped from the backstack. Likewise the `popExitAnim` is applied to the destination when itself is popped from the backstack.

Let me clarify with an example as well. Let's assume below navigation graph:

```xml
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/example_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_a">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_a"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentA">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/from_a_to_b"
            app:destination="@id/destination_b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_bottom"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/scale_out_center"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/scale_in_center"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_b"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentB">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/from_b_to_c"
            app:destination="@id/destination_c" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_c"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentC" />
</navigation>
```

As we launch the target Activity we will be looking at FragmentA. In this example we will navigate from FragmentA -> FragmentB -> FragmentC -> Back -> Back, only by using the defined `<action>`'s and the system back button.

So, navigating from FragmentA to FragmentB will:

- Hide FragmentA with default animations
- Show FragmentB with the `slide_in_bottom` animation ("enterAnim")

Further on, navigating from FragmentB to FragmentC will:

- Show FragmentC with default animations, and
- Remove FragmentB with `scale_out_center` animation ("exitAnim")

On our way back, pressing the system back button will:

- Remove FragmentC from the backstack with default animations
- Show FragmentB with the `scale_in_center` animation ("popEnterAnim")

Pressing the system back button again will:

- Hide FragmentB with the `slide_out_bottom` animation ("popExitAnim")
- Show FragmentA with default animations